# Can I set a flag on an object in a push method?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a Node.js/Express app and I would like to send a boolean on the push method.

```
exports.registerUserForCompetition = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { _id, name, email } = req.body;
  const competition = await Competition.findById(req.params.id);

    const newUser = {
    _id,
    name,
    email,
  };

  competition.registeredUsers.push({newUser, $set:{isRegistered: true});
  await competition.save();
  res.json(competition);
```

It is not working of course.
Is there a way to achieve this somehow?
on my User schema I have a field for this

```
isRegistered: Boolean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `newUser` is an object so you can just set `isRegistered` field when declare it:

```
const newUser = {
  _id,
  name,
  email,
  isRegistered: true
};
```

Or when push new user to array:

```
competition.registeredUsers.push({...newUser, isRegistered: true});
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Tried the same just forgot the spread operator. :)